# How to run a DC device through 3 phase 400V AC mains?

Tags: ac, dc, three-phase, full-bridge

So I need to put a wifi antenna on farmland, the issue is that the antenna needs 12V DC  powered over Ethernet and the only power source nearby is a 3phase 400V AC one...

So is there something like a full bridge rectifier I could buy to do that or an other sort of converter/adapter?

Comment: Is the supply three-phase with neutral or three phase without neutral?

Comment: You should have no problem finding an AC to DC converter that can supply an isolated 12V from 400VAC. You can run it from any two phase wires. https://www.pulspower.com/us/products/din-rail-power-supplies/3-phase-power-supplies/

Comment: what's at the other end of the ethernet cable?

Answer (score 2):

If you have neutral, just hook a common Europlug or whatever to neutral and any one of the phases.

If you don't have neutral, get a small 400V to 230V single phase transformer, you only need like 20-30 VA.  Then connect the output of the transformer to a Europlug.

Then, plug any random commodity 12 volt power supply into the Europlug.  The antenna probably comes with one!

If you can't find a sanely priced 400V to 230V isolation transformer, then look for a hobby transformer that supports both 230V and 400V on the primary side, and we do not care what is on the secondary side. Connect the two 400V phases to the two 400V primary lugs.  Connect the 230V Europlug to the two 230V primary lugs (note that one of the lugs will be the same). Connect nothing to the secondary; won't need it.

Comment: A proper installation will make sure that electrical code is followed. In the US you would need over-current protection (fuse or breaker) and a way to disconnect (disconnect switch or breaker or both). I suspect OP does have neutral. So this could be an easy install.

Comment: @mkeith Yeah I agree, I kinda breezed past the Code part which is unusual for me.  I just don't know Euro codes or parts availability, I was knocking wood there are COTS packaged products (equivalent to UL-listed consumer ready products) and/or 400V receps in their ecosystem. The "use the primary side of a hobby transformer for a stepdown" would definitely require a proper enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

Should you have access to a 3 x 400V~ 4-wire system, a 230V~ input DC power supply, connected between line and neutral, would suffice.

With a 3 x 400V~ 3-wire system, you would require a 400V~ input DC power supply, connected between two lines.

Comment: I dont understand is it as easy as putting the DC device plug into the 3 phase power inlet ?

Comment: Hi papajo, I suppose we need to look at the bigger picture. Do you intend setting up an outdoor wireless modem router with  Sim card, 4G and WiFi antennas, Ethernet cable and PoE Injector? Where does the Ethernet cable lead to? Is your 3 x 400V~ power source fused and terminated in a sheltered place? Is your power source a 4 wire system (with Neutral)?

Comment: vu2nan its a farming field i has three phase power in a smal shed to power the water pump, I want to send internet from my home to that field in order to do that I need to buy ubuiquiti antennas.. those need DC power though the issue is simple.. i just cant find a solution that doesnt cost 1000+++ dollars and industrial lol

Comment: If you have neutral out there, then literally any wall wart power supply off any old router or LED toy or whatever ought to do the job for you.  The thing you're looking for is manufacture *by the billions*.  You'll recognize it instantly when you see one!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica So I just use the power transformer from my device and connect the 2 wires of the 3 phase to it and nothing will explode?

Comment: Yeah. If your three phase power is 400V line to line, and 230V line to neutral, and you have neutral available, you can install any old 230V converter from line to Neutral. There will be electrical codes that apply and the work should be done properly to avoid fire hazards and shock hazards, but it is not super difficult. You will want to take care of fusing and adding a disconnect switch between the main installation and your add-on box with the converter in it.

Comment: @papajo Nono, if you connect two phases you get 400V, and your power supply might not like that too much. If you just wire it to a common plug, connect to phase and neutral. DO NOT connect to phase and ground.  If you don't have neutral there, it won't work, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

You probably should plan on isolated power.

So hunt for a suitable transformer, 400vac to 12/15 vac.

A dual primary rated 220vac, with 10/12/15/18 secondary, gives you design freedom.

A fullwave rectifier will give you 18/25 volts no load. Pick its "repetitive peak current" to be 50x your DC_current. Use wide foil on the leads, over gnd plane, to remove heat and have long life.

For every 0.1 amp DC load, use 470 uf on output of rectifier, and expect 2 volts of ripple at 120Hz.

A linear regulator in TO-220  package, heatsinked to 6" by 6" metal side of your case, will provide the 12 volts.

Plan on fuses, and EMI L+C filters before the transformer.

Comment: I understood hardly half of what you said... I only want to power a wifi modem router and a antenna .... googling adapters from 3phase to dc only yield some very expensive cabin size industrial hardware....

Comment: https://www.pulspower.com/us/products/din-rail-power-supplies/3-phase-power-supplies/

Comment: @mkeith yea that should work I am looking to achieve that exact thing the downside is that this costs like 500 euro where I live... I just want to power a modem router (12V 1A and a antenna 8V 1A)  and dont want to buy two seperate units such as those and spend 1000 euro for that.. :P

Comment: 12V battery + battery charger may also work.

Comment: There should be something available for only 100 euros or so I would think. These would be widely needed in industrial applications where the controls are wired at low voltage for safety. So I would expect anyway.

Comment: Maybe the 400V stuff is just a lot more expensive. It would be worth discovering if you have neutral available.